# radio object not checked when copy the contents of div with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm having problem **input[type=radio]** with jquery.

I need to do to copying the contents of div, but keeping default checked of a radio object

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    var copy = '<div id="source">';
    copy += $('#source').html();
    copy += '</div>';
    $(this).after(copy);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7EFb/

Please help me!

Comment: Your copying is cloning IDs which is a no-no. Also, you're essentially extending your group of radio buttons which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @j08691 Not only IDs but name attributes as well.

Comment: so in your fiddle .. you are wrong because only one radio can be checked at time. means you violate html ..that's why state is not maintained of radios

Comment: also name must not be the same

Comment: Im a little confused, at _#source_ first, when i click on the _#copy_, will unset checked of a radio object http://jsfiddle.net/R7EFb/1/

Comment: after copying you have six radios and all have same name.4 have checked so dom confused itself and gives you some only...

Comment: only solution is to put this copy into iframe..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different name attribute  and IDs for the copied radio button sets and there labels.

Here is an [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/R7EFb/6/).

```
var copyCount = 1;

$("#copy").click(function() {
    $("#source").clone().attr("id", "source" + copyCount).appendTo("body");
    // Get original radio elements
    $radio1 = $("#source" + copyCount + " #radio1");
    $radio2 = $("#source" + copyCount + " #radio2");
    $radio3 = $("#source" + copyCount + " #radio3");
    $radio4 = $("#source" + copyCount + " #radio4");

    // Change attributes (name and id)
    $radio1.attr("id", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 1)).attr("name", "check" + (copyCount * 2 + 1)).next().attr("for", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 1));
    $radio2.attr("id", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 2)).attr("name", "check" + (copyCount * 2 + 1)).next().attr("for", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 2));
    $radio3.attr("id", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 3)).attr("name", "check" + (copyCount * 2 + 2)).next().attr("for", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 3));
    $radio4.attr("id", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 4)).attr("name", "check" + (copyCount * 2 + 2)).next().attr("for", "radio" + (copyCount * 4 + 4));

    // Restore selected option in original radio set
    if ($radio1.attr("checked") !== undefined) $("#source #radio1").click();
    if ($radio2.attr("checked") !== undefined) $("#source #radio2").click();
    if ($radio3.attr("checked") !== undefined) $("#source #radio3").click();
    if ($radio4.attr("checked") !== undefined) $("#source #radio4").click();

    copyCount++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Clone without duplicating the Id's, Names and for attributes if any.
Please check the Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R7EFb/5/).

Please see the globalVarCount is the variable that differentiates these. Here's the Code::

```
var globalVarCount= 0;
$('#copy').click(function() {
    var copy;
    $clone = $("#source").clone();
    $clone.attr("id",$clone.attr("id")+1)
    $clone.children().each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id")+1);
        $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name")+1);
        $(this).attr("for",$(this).attr("for")+1);
    });
    $(this).after($clone);
});
```